# Get random documents/records from MongoDB with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, random

Below I have a bit of Java code to get all records/documents from a collection

```
    DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("collection");

    BasicDBObject select = new BasicDBObject();
    select.put("title", 1);
    select.put("name", 1);

    String random = JSON.serialize(collection.find(select));
```

Now I would like to get say 10 documents random from the collection.

How would I do this? Is this possible?

I have found many questions of others but not a real solution. I have about 1500 documents in the collection. Speed is not very important.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: do you want to have any specific distribution? Should every document have the same probability to be chosen?

Comment: Yes if possible every document have the same probability to be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tip for you: **embed each document with random number** (e.g. from 0..1 interval) and **use range queries to extract random documents**.

For example, assume, we have collection `test`.

In shell you can embed each document from this collection with random number in such way (with server side script):

```
db.eval(
   function(){
      db.test.find().forEach(
         function(obj){
            obj.rnd = Math.random();
            db.test.save(obj);
         })})
```

And extract random document (this query can be simply translated to use in java):

```
db.test.findOne({"rnd" : {"$gte" : Math.random()}})
```

So, if you generate documents from your code: before persisting just **add field with random value into your documents**. Otherwise, if you only have access to collection - **use server side js to embed each document with random-valued field**.

With simple loop you can extract so many random documents as you want, but of course, you have to handle situations when the same document extracts more than once (or if no documents matched query).

Comment: It is an interesting solution but if I am not mistaken not every element has the same probability to be chosen because of the $gte function. An example: 
if you have 10 documents with "rnd" objects equal to: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, and the Math.random() in your query returns 0.3 than the elements with "rnd" >= 0.3 will have a higher chance of being selected than the once before.

Comment: @peshkira, every time you want to get random document, you have to run query with random number. So, every time `Math.random()` returns random number - it means that each element has the same probability being found. As I know, this tip with random number is a standard trick.

Comment: hmm, may be I miss something but I don't think the result of the query orders the elements. It could be that the first random returns 0.3 and you select the object with 0.7 and than the next random returns 0.4 and you select again another object with 0.7, just because your query returns documents with "rnd" >= 0.3 and 0.4 respectively. I would be grateful if you can point me to some external source describing this trick. cheers!

Comment: @peshkira, yes, you're right, there might be situation, when the same document will be matched for different random thresholds. To avoid this, we can add sorting in query: `db.test.find({"rnd" : {"$gte" : Math.random()}}).sort({"rnd" : 1}).limit(1)`

Comment: @peshkira, you can read about this trick in book: http://www.amazon.com/MongoDB-Definitive-Guide-Kristina-Chodorow/dp/1449381561%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIIBINOD46VC3JCLQ%26tag%3Dstackoverfl08-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D1449381561

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is called *[Systematic Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematic_sampling)*.

Here is one way you can achieve it:

```
//...
List<DBObject> result = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("collection");
long count = collection.getCount();
int limit = 10; //or whatever you want

if (count <= limit) {
  DBCursor cursor = collection.find(select);
  while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    result.add(cursor.next());
  }

} else {
  long skip = Math.round((double) count / limit);

  DBCursor cursor = collection.find(select);

  while (result.size() < limit) {
    int offset = (int) ((skip * result.size() + (int) ((Math.random() * skip) % count)) % count);
    System.out.println(offset);
    DBObject next = cursor.skip(offset).next();
    result.add(next);

    cursor = collection.find(select);
  }

}
```

basically it collects all documents if their count is smaller than the desired limit. If not
it calculates a skip that is equal to N (overall count) / n (your limit).
Then the a random offset is calculated which is always between 0 and the skip, however the iteration is considered.

As an example if you have 100 documents and you want 10 random samples you will get
one random sample for each of the following buckets: 1-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-40, 41-50, 51-60, 61-70, 71-80, 81-90, 91-100.